# String becomes null when transfered

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to pass two variables to another ViewController: username and api_key. the username works fine, and is set to the correct value, but the api_key is null.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"loginSuccess"]) {
        myServersViewController *controller = (myServersViewController*)[segue destinationViewController];
        controller.api_key = key;
        controller.username = usernameField.text;
    }
}

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSuccess" sender:self];
            key = array[1];
```

array[1] is not null and has the correct value.

```
@interface ViewController () {
    NSString *key;
}
```

And now for the other viewcontroller:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *api_key;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *username;

NSLog(@"%@, %@", api_key, username);
```

Output:

```
(null), test
```

Comment: This is not real code. Show your real code.

Answer (score 0):

If the `username` property is showing correctly then it has to be an issue with your `key` variable. Where are you assigning it? Place a break point before it or `NSLog` the value of key before assigning it. I'm sure it's `null` for some reason outside of the code posted above.

Answer (score 0):

This is not real code and makes no sense:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *api_key;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *username;

NSLog(@"%@, %@", api_key, username);
```

You can't log just any old time in the middle of nowhere. You have to do it *inside some method* that runs at some definite time in the life of the view controller.

Comment: the properties are in the the .h files of the second view controller.

Comment: But what I am saying is that the NSLog statement cannot be there too. You need to show your actual code in its actual context - not just a bunch of disjointed snippets without saying where the code lives.

Answer (score 0):

Make your "key" variable another strong property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *api_keyForSegue;
```

And I renamed it something a bit more descriptive.